StoreKit requestReview popup in macOS SwiftUI app appears behind app window, how to fix it?
I have a following macOS app in SwiftUI:
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

@main
struct TestAppApp: App {
    @Environment(\.requestReview) private var requestReview: RequestReviewAction
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(minWidth: 800, idealWidth: 800, minHeight: 600, idealHeight: 600)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: {
                        print("requestReview")
//                        requestReview.callAsFunction()
                        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
                    })
                })
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

It shows a popup used for asking for a rating/review after 3 seconds from launching the app. The problem with it is that the StoreKit popup appears behind the main window of the app so user will not notice it unless he moves the main window on the screen. The problem appears no matter if I use SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() or requestReview.callAsFunction() (commented in above code). Is there any way to fix it in such way that this popup appears in front of app window so that user can actually see it?
Note that this popup not always appears when launching the app (which is normal) so while testing it might be needed to change the bundle identifier of the app to a new one before launching to make sure the popup appears.

unrelated but .callAsFunction() does exactly what it would imply: it allows you to call the type instance as a function: requestReview()
